# How to run external ruta scripts from a maven project without placing the script or its typesystem in the classpath?

Tags: maven, uima, ruta

Till now, I had been running ruta scripts from a maven project by creating AnalysisEngine and CAS, and processing the engine. To do this, I had placed all the scripts and descriptor files (Engine & TypeSystem) into scr/main/resources folder of the maven project.

Now I want to place the scripts and TypeSystem files in an external path and pass the path dynamically to my java code that runs the scripts. Is it possible to do it ? If so, how ?

I simply placed the files(script & descriptor) in an external path and passed the new path to instantiate the AnalysisEngine as below;

```
final AnalysisEngine engine = AnalysisEngineFactory.createEngine("home/admin/Desktop/TEST_ScriptFolder/com/textjuicer/ruta/date/Dazzle_ChapRef_UpdatedEngine");
```

**Error**

org.apache.uima.util.InvalidXMLException: An import could not be resolved.  No file with name "home/admin/Desktop/TEST_ScriptFolder/com/textjuicer/ruta/date/Dazzle_ChapRef_UpdatedEngine.xml" was found in the class path or data path. (Descriptor: )
    at org.apache.uima.resource.metadata.impl.Import_impl.findAbsoluteUrl(Import_impl.java:117)
    at org.apache.uima.fit.factory.AnalysisEngineFactory.createEngineDescription(AnalysisEngineFactory.java:869)
    at org.apache.uima.fit.factory.AnalysisEngineFactory.createEngine(AnalysisEngineFactory.java:107)
    at com.textjuicer.ruta.date.ArtifactAnnotator.getAllAnnotations(ArtifactAnnotator.java:93)
    at ApplyingStyle.XmiTransformer.parseXMI(XmiTransformer.java:33)
    at ApplyingStyle.ApplyStyle.applyStyleOnDocx(ApplyStyle.java:76)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two layers:

1. The RutaEngine needs to find the scripts/resources/descriptors
2. UIMA needs to be able to resolve imports of descriptors

The resource lookup in Ruta has two stages, it searches for them in the absolute paths specified in the configuration parameters. If the resource is not found it searches for it in the classpath. So you need to set the configuration parameters: scripts are located in `scriptPaths`, descriptors are located in `descriptorPaths` and wordlists are located in `resourcePaths`. See the [documentation](http://ps://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.ae.basic) for further information.

The problems with the imports in descriptors can be solved by either setting the datapath in the UIMA ResourceManager or by changing the import to "location" instead of "name". The datapath can be used as a replacement for the classpath. The Ruta descriptos use import by location if it specified int he ruta-maven-plugin.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: Thanks ! Is it possible to set a variable (path) instead of hard coding the path in the engine file ? Because I want to fetch the path dynamically (java) and pass it to the engine file. Is there a way to do it straight forward?

Comment: Or... is it possible to get the current path from within the engine file and set the same as script path, resource path & descriptor path ?

Comment: You can always reconfigure the analysis engine (changing the parameter values) programmatically. If the analysis engine description was based on an xml descriptor, then it stores also its original url.

Comment: Please let me know how to do it programatically. I've asked it as a new question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721977/how-to-reconfigure-uima-ruta-analysis-engine-change-the-parameter-values-progr)