# Using UIMA Ruta outside of Eclipse: Problem with absolute paths / Compilation

Tags: java, uima, ruta

I am trying to use a UIMA Ruta script created in Eclipse with a Java webserver in plain Java based on [these instructions](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.ae.basic.apply), but I'm running into problems due to the fact that `scriptPaths`, `descriptorPaths` and `resourcePaths` are absolute paths. Is there a way to compile UIMA Ruta scripts with relative paths, or, ideally, to compile UIMA Ruta scripts outside of Eclipse?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These absolute paths are optional as the files can also be resolved using the classpath. There is also the option to use the UIMA datapath to resolve the descriptors and scripts.

In plain Java, make sure that the context of these folder are in the classpath and just remove the absolute folder from the configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Peter. Adding the folders to the classpath or data path is a partial solution, but how does one remove these folders from the configuration? I'm working with a UIMA Ruta Eclipse project with the default settings.

Comment: I think you could actually ignore them as the classpath lookup wins. If the existence of the paths is not desirable, then you probably need to switch to the ruta-maven-plugin

Comment: Thank you again. The switch to maven is something that is definitely preferable, especially since I would like to automate the process as much as possible, however, it brings with itself another set of problems (on which later). Another solution could be the one you proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721977/how-to-reconfigure-uima-ruta-analysis-engine-change-the-parameter-values-progr), correct?